Why does Jesus give an action of Yahweh as an example of evil?
In Matthew 7 Jesus says,
(KJV)

9 Or what man is there of you, whom if his son ask bread, will he give him a stone?
10 Or if he ask a fish, will he give him a serpent?
11 If ye then, being evil, know how to give good gifts unto your children, how much more shall your Father which is in heaven give good things to them that ask him?

(Berean Greek Bible)

9 Ἢ τίς ἐστιν ἐξ ὑμῶν ἄνθρωπος, ὃν αἰτήσει ὁ υἱὸς αὐτοῦ ἄρτον, μὴ λίθον ἐπιδώσει αὐτῷ;
10 ἢ καὶ ἰχθὺν αἰτήσει, μὴ ὄφιν ἐπιδώσει αὐτῷ;
11 εἰ οὖν ὑμεῖς πονηροὶ ὄντες οἴδατε δόματα ἀγαθὰ διδόναι τοῖς τέκνοις ὑμῶν, πόσῳ μᾶλλον ὁ Πατὴρ ὑμῶν ὁ ἐν τοῖς οὐρανοῖς δώσει ἀγαθὰ τοῖς αἰτοῦσιν αὐτόν.

In Numbers 21 it is written,
(KJV)

4 And they journeyed from mount Hor by the way of the Red sea, to compass the land of Edom: and the soul of the people was much discouraged because of the way.
5 And the people spake against God, and against Moses, Wherefore have ye brought us up out of Egypt to die in the wilderness? for there is no bread, neither is there any water; and our soul loatheth this light bread.
6 And the LORD sent fiery serpents among the people, and they bit the people; and much people of Israel died.

(Westminster Leningrad Codex)

וַיִּסְע֞וּ מֵהֹ֤ר הָהָר֙ דֶּ֣רֶךְ יַם־ס֔וּף לִסְבֹ֖ב אֶת־אֶ֣רֶץ אֱדֹ֑ום וַתִּקְצַ֥ר נֶֽפֶשׁ־הָעָ֖ם בַּדָּֽרֶךְ׃
וַיְדַבֵּ֣ר הָעָ֗ם בֵּֽאלֹהִים֮ וּבְמֹשֶׁה֒ לָמָ֤ה הֶֽעֱלִיתֻ֙נוּ֙ מִמִּצְרַ֔יִם לָמ֨וּת בַּמִּדְבָּ֑ר כִּ֣י אֵ֥ין לֶ֙חֶם֙ וְאֵ֣ין מַ֔יִם וְנַפְשֵׁ֣נוּ קָ֔צָה בַּלֶּ֖חֶם הַקְּלֹקֵֽל׃
וַיְשַׁלַּ֨ח יְהוָ֜ה בָּעָ֗ם אֵ֚ת הַנְּחָשִׁ֣ים הַשְּׂרָפִ֔ים וַֽיְנַשְּׁכ֖וּ אֶת־הָעָ֑ם וַיָּ֥מָת עַם־רָ֖ב מִיִּשְׂרָאֵֽל׃

When Yahweh's children asked him for bread, he gave them serpents. Yet Jesus uses almost this exact example to set the standard he expects even evil humans to exceed. How can this be interpreted?

Objection: "They rejected the bread"
The word translated by KJV as 'light' in the phrase 'light bread' in Numbers 21:5 is הַקְּלֹקֵֽל׃ = haq·qə·lō·qêl, which BDB translates as 'contemptible, worthless'. The people feel they are here 'to die' for lack of bread/food, despite having this 'worthless bread'.
There seems to me to be an easy way to understand this: the 'worthless bread' is 'worthless' in the sense of not being nutritious enough to sustain the people in their environment. I know from experience the feeling of loathing non-nutritious food when I'm hungry. Yahweh immediately shows that he is willing for the people to die if he wishes, so perhaps the 'worthless bread' was indeed non-nutritious, as a test or punishment or for some other reason.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

When Yahweh's children asked him for bread, he gave them serpents.
But they didn't ask:

… if his son ask bread …
… if he ask a fish …

They complained:

… the people spake against God
… Wherefore have ye brought us up out of Egypt to die in the wilderness?
… for there is no bread, neither is there any water

That's a very significant difference, and a completely different situation.

but which would you rather have: a father who gives you a stone when you wanted bread, or a father who gives you a stone when you needed bread and then kills you for complaining?

@FelixLXX How about a father who gives you manna when you need bread? Their problem is not that God didn't take care of them, it's that they rejected what He did to take care of them. This is the one point missing from an otherwise great answer.

Exactly, @user111403. "Now the house of Israel called its name manna. It was like coriander seed, white, and the taste of it was like wafers made with honey." - Exodus 16:31 ESV. Jesus, who was born in Bethlehem (house of bread), described himself as the bread of life. We also read in 1 Corinthians 10:4 ESV, "And all drank the same spiritual drink. For they drank from the spiritual Rock that followed them, and the Rock was Christ." And that's not all. There's living water, and there's wine as the blood of the New Covenant.

@user111403 that's better because God cannot be left resembling a moronic snake-throwing pedant. But there is still a serious contention that the manna was providence and not an obligation of the covenant, which means their freedom of will has been suspended without warning. And disobedience was cursed in Deuteronomy but if the Israelites must tread on such eggshells where has God told them this deserves death.

@user111403 I've edited the OP to address the manna objection. If the Israelites feel the manna is 'worthless', so strongly that they feel they are here 'to die', I think that's a plausible complaint. It certainly is possible for food to be 'worthless' in the sense of non-nutritous, and Yahweh immediately shows that he is willing for them do die if he wishes. Perhaps the manna was intentionally worthless as a test.

Ray Butterworth, Jesus is giving the love of a normal, evil, human father for his son as a minimal standard to contrast how far 'your Father' exceeds this. If a son said to his father, "Dad, I can't eat this food you gave me, it's no good. I feel like I'm going to die of hunger.", and the father responded by giving the son a serpent which killed the son, would that still illustrate Jesus example of a minimally caring father? I think not.

No, it's not a completely different situation, just a more specific version of the more general one. It's clear that they wanted bread (perhaps different, better, more, bread--but bread of some kind). They were given serpents instead. To be sure, in addition to wanting something, they complained about (among other things) not having it, and blamed the persons they thought were being stingy. But clearly not unreasonably. An "evil" (that is, morally imperfect) but caring earthly father would certainly have given bread. How much more so would the heavenly father do so? Not much, clearly.

Ray Butterworth, I also think "spoke against God" shouldn't contribute to the 'complaint' characterisation, since the preposition translated as 'against' is translated in 21 of the 23 places where it occurs bound to 'elohim' as 'in', 'through', 'by', 'for', or 'of' rather than 'against'. 'against' seems to be a translator fitting a flexible word to the context as he sees it, rather than the intrinsic meaning of the word.

@mjc "Perhaps the manna was intentionally worthless as a test." That is certainly not supported by the text. It says that they lived on it for forty years--long enough to be perfectly bored of the stuff, while also empirically showing it to be a complete food.

@mjc says "'against' seems to be a translator fitting a flexible word to the context as he sees it, rather than the intrinsic meaning of the word" — yet every translator seems to have made the same mistake.

Also they had bread, and it was sufficient, they just got tired of it and didn’t value it as the awesome miraculous provision of God that it was.

@Conrado Point taken about the 40 years as evidence for the nutritional value. I would say the Israelites' complaint resulting from their being heartily sick of the food after that long would still put Yahweh's capital punishment on the wrong side of Jesus' illustration.

Ray Butterworth: I don't say the translation is a mistake, just not evidence for the 'complaint' characterisation. Translators agreeing on it isn't hard to understand, it seems to me, if they all have a similar interpretation of what's going on, based on context and perhaps presuppositions; but that doesn't make a polysemic preposition into a monosemic one.

I think it's important to note that God the Father must act like a father to Israel, His children. When the children whine and demand and complain, the father needs to show greater wisdom than giving them exactly what they ask for when they ask for it. Otherwise, the children become spoiled, self-centered, narcissistic, and unloving. In the same way, we today must ask for things that God wants for us, not things we want out of our own self-centeredness. See James 4:2-3.

I think Ray Butterworth answers the original question perfectly, with the added comment that God in fact provided manna. This is in response to the objection that the OP added later:
The OP argues that "the 'worthless bread' is 'worthless' in the sense of not being nutritious enough to sustain the people in their environment". To accept that position, we have to discard a lot of other Scripture. For example:

Exodus 16:35 - And the children of Israel did eat manna 40 years...


Psalm 78:24-25 - And had rained down manna upon them to eat, and had given them of the corn of heaven. 25 Man did eat angels' food: he sent them meat to the full.

Manna sustained them for 40 years. It's explicitly stated to be "meat to the full". Just because the Israelites said it was worthless doesn't mean it actually was worthless. It seems clear from the rest of Scripture that this isn't a case of God failing to provide, it's a case of people refusing to accept God's provision.
In fact we see this pattern repeating in this same story if we read a few verses further. After the serpents appear, God again provides. He gives them the brass serpent. All the people have to do is accept God's provision, look at the serpent and be saved. Only the people who again reject what God offers them will die.
We can see the same pattern repeating today. One of the clearest texts on this is John 3:16-18. God gave His Son to be the savior of the world. But many people reject Him, either rejecting God's existence or trying to earn their salvation in another way. Once again, those who believe in God and accept His provision are saved, those who reject Him are condemned.
Given this pattern that we can clearly see throughout history and the context of Scripture, it seems clear to me that Numbers 21 is another example of the same thing, and not in fact a case of God actually giving them something worthless.

but קְלֹקֵל is a hapax legomenon so it mightn't mean worthless at all. Their problem might be that it's legally-uncertain or 'fishy' rather than anything to do with its nutritional value

@FelixLXX Perhaps so (I'm not really qualified to comment), but I don't think it's material to the argument. Just because they said there was a problem, it doesn't follow that there actually was a problem.

To think they were complaining about nothing (and perhaps by extension deserved death) draws the least value from the lesson and hobbles apologetics with the appearance that it cannot answer questions. And well, you have not just commended but answered. To read the passage at all we must supply meaning to  קְלֹקֵל, and it must be a meaning that credits the ones smitten with having been faithful enough to follow Moses into the desert. What about "stealable" and the snakes are biting the thieves?

@FelixLXX I can read context. It's clear from the context that the word is some sort of complaint (and that your alternate "explanation" is not plausible). I can't comment on the precise nature of the complaint, but we don't need to know precisely what they called the bread to understand the text. They don't have bread, except that they actually do have bread but they don't like it.

user111403, I agree that Psalm 78 supports the interpretation that the manna was sufficient. But if it was so good, why would the Israelites prefer normal food/bread so much that they felt they might die in a place they described as lacking any food? That sounds to me like they had (or thought they had) a real problem with the food. Since I'm not committed to Biblical inerrancy, I think one explanation would be a later Psalmist editorialising to smooth over criticisms of Yahweh.

@mjc I don't think even the immediate context supports the reading that things were actually as bad as they said in their complaint. If we discard Biblical inerrancy and internal consistency, then how can we have any confidence that this story is reported accurately?

@user111403 We can have the same sort of limited confidence we have in other historical reports, and make the same sort of criticisms, based on internal textual evidence, archaeology, parallel traditions, etc. I expect you're aware of the popular theory that the OT had several authors with different motives.

Your reference to John 3:16-18 within the context of a discussion of Numbers 21 is apropos.  See John 3:15.  The point of Numbers 21 is to answer the question, "How do you fix a whiner?"  Answer: You send them a very significant challenge that they can't fix no matter how much they complain about it, and you provide a solution that requires no effort on their part--"just look at the snake on the pole".  The full context of "Yahweh sent poisonous snakes" is to understand that it's more gift than punishment.  John 3:16 is the reality to the Numbers 21 archetype.

@mjc Of course I'm aware of the theory. I'm just very skeptical of a method of interpretation that allows me to pick and choose which parts I'm going to believe as a means to find truth. From there it's a very small step to cherry-picking texts that support my preconceptions, and I can very easily become the arbiter of truth rather than God and the Bible.

user111403 I see that drawback. I don't know why that's a better argument for assuming the inerrancy of the Bible than of the Qur'an or the Vedas or the Talmud; or who other than you is arbitrating your choice of which if any text to regard as inerrant; or how you avoid arguing in circles if you say the God of the inerrant Bible is arbitrating your choice to regard the Bible as inerrant.

I don't think the quote "he sent them meat to the full" is talking about the manna; it's talking about the quail that God gave the Israelites their fill of, at that point in the Psalm.

@mjc I readily admit that this isn't an argument to disprove the theory. It's rather questioning whether the theory even leaves us a framework for meaningful inquiry. Similarly, if I was going to discuss Islamic teaching, to have any meaningful discussion I'd have to start from the assumption that the Quran is true and accurate, even though I personally believe that assumption to be false. In any case, this supports my statement. To accept your position, we have to discard other Scripture. It's up to you if you're willing to do that, as long as you understand that you are discarding.

@mbomb007 Read the verse in context and you'll see that the psalmist starts talking about the quail after this verse. Note that "meat" in the KJV just means "food" in modern English, while when referring to quail in verse 27 he says "flesh", which does correspond to the modern meaning of "meat". In context, verse 25 is unambiguously referring to manna.

user11403 Point taken. At present picking and choosing scriptures (according to some consistent theory) is easy for me to accept.

The example does not cite an action of Yahweh's evil.  It is a standard Greek rhetorical device known as an argument of contrast - man is sinful (and thus evil) contrasted with the perfect and holy God of Yahweh.
Jesus says as much in His conclusion:

Matt 7:11 - If ye then, being evil, know how to give good gifts unto
your children, how much more shall your Father which is in heaven give
good things to them that ask him?

This also amounts to an argument from the lesser (man) to the greater, God.

This called a kal v'chomer argument. It appears frequently in the scriptures, but I think it's often considered a Talmudic argument. In Latin it's called an argument a fortiori. However, I'm unaware of what it's called in Greek or whether the Greeks used it.

@Dieter - good points.  Many thanks

Dottard, The audience is evil compared with 'your Father' (not named here as Yahweh); the comparison is illustrated by observing that even evil humans wouldn't do something as mean as giving their son a serpent when he asked for a fish. Therefore anyone who would do such a thing is even more evil than the audience. But Yahweh does such a thing. This could support an argument that the Yahweh of the OT is not the Father praised by Jesus - either along the lines of Marcionism, or along the lines of false additions/edits by self-interested scribes and Pharisees, whom Jesus criticises and corrects.

@mjc - Your assumption is simply untrue - God does not give evil gifts - the text does NOT say this.

Dottard, the text doesn't say Yahweh's children asked for bread and he gave them serpents? I'll need some explanation to follow you there. Presumably you don't doubt that Yahweh repeatedly and intentionally afflicts his people, as test or punishment?

Dottard, mjc didn't say or assume that the text said God gave evil gifts. He concluded this from the plain text of the scripture. Your original response, OTOH, is misleading when saying "The example does not cite an action of Yahweh's evil." mjc's original question does not say that Jesus was /citing/ an example of Yahweh doing evil. Rather, Jesus gives an example contrasting good with evil (giving wanted bread vs. giving a serpent), and mjc points out that Yahweh, as a matter of fact (assuming scripture to be valid) violates exactly this example.

Unusually, a Jesus-Myth approach offers a good solution to this that doesn't rely on nobody in the story being real. It bears rehearsing:-
In Matthew 7:9, Jesus doesn't mention the book of Numbers and God is in the target of the analogy by extension not the source by allusion. We live in a quotation-culture where references to the bible are assumed to be faithful, noticeable to the listeners (with their online access to Strong's),  and not to be contending for amendments to the scripture.
But this involves a bundle of assumptions about what intellectual climate Matthew and Jesus were working in.
Following after Robert Price, it might be that Matthew is attributing a Cynic aphorism to Jesus, and only using the book of Numbers to flesh out the wording or to Judaize the style for his particular audience.
Price links the OP's passage to these ones:- https://archive.org/details/DeconstructingJesus/page/n307/mode/2up?q=%22a+stone%22

And our parent has put close to hand whatever is going to be to our
good. (Seneca - 65AD)
People blame the gods because they don’t make them rich with lots of
nice things—but they don’t blame their own disposition to stupidity.
They must be blind to refute the really good gifts the daimon gives.
(Pseudo-Heraclitus - 1st C AD)

But Meyer's commentary has a much better one:-

"With one hand he bears a stone, with the other he shows bread."
(Plautus - ~200BC)

And Henry Thomas Riley's commentary on Plautus quotes this late medieval explanation:

"Erasmus says that it was applied to those who pretended to be
friendly to a person, and at the same time were doing him mischief;
and that it was borrowed from persons enticing a dog with a piece of
bread, and, when it had come sufficiently near, pelting it with a
stone."

(Chapter 8 under the heading 'Hero Stories' is where Price discusses the theory that the gospel writers often used the OT as a style-source without bringing over its theological significance.)
Matthew certainly does quote the OT like we do, for example at 27:9 "Then what was spoken by Jeremiah the prophet was fulfilled." Which is firstly a misquote (since the prophet he means is Zechariah), but secondly and more to the point this might be how Matthew introduces quotes.
The OP's passage doesn't have any sort of citation-formula. There isn't an "it is written" or a "the prophets have said" or a "verily I say unto thee".
And the aphorism certainly doesn't rely on the Numbers passage to make sense - or it wouldn't be in the contemporary Cynics, plus a stage comedy from two-hundred years earlier.
And it isn't verbatim apart from the key terms ὄφιν and ἄρτον. Jesus' phrasing is closer to Plautus than Moses.
All of which points to this not being Matthew having Jesus giving God as an example of evil. The verbal similarity to Numbers 21 is accidental.
And Erasmus isn't an authority on 1st-Century pranking, but he does open that the aphorism Jesus uses might not be applicable to the situation in Numbers 21, as it first appears.
Jesus' aphorism isn't just that you wanted bread and got a stone boo hoo. It's that the parent tempted you with bread and switched it for a stone at the last second.
Whatever is going on in Numbers 21 it isn't that God offered the Israelites manna and then said "aha! tricked you! you get a burning snake!"

Jesus-Myth approaches would also want to look at whether Jesus is using the aphorism to throw shade at Numbers 21 (or over-zealous interpretations of it), as part of a liberalizing project. But that isn't needed for the OP's question.

If Matthew is writing to a diaspora audience, or to the community of diaspora Jews who returned to Judea (which was large enough to need its own synagogues), their forebears hadn't followed Moses, so Numbers 21 might read very differently for them.

Fundamentalist interpretation
This shouldn't need to be said here but the contentions are raised and the downvotes are predictable.
If people want to tell others (i) that the bible is infallible and (ii) what it means, they cannot admit that Jesus uses adages. They say:-
Jesus can't be quoting Plautus! (for some reason)
But that isn't at all the contention, it's that the Greek language possessed an adage which we know of from Plautus and also a couple of contemporary Cynic philosophers.
Jesus never uses adages! We can always tell what he means from a New Testament or Old Testament source (again for some reason)
The hazard becomes obvious. To admit that Jesus uses the Greek language in the same way as every other user of the Greek language (i.e. as a language) is to admit that we can only tell what he is saying in Matthew 7:9 thanks to Plautus. And we only have Plautus thanks to luck.
We have lost 90% of the Ancient Greek textual corpus, and 100% of the spoken corpus (in context of perhaps a 3% literacy rate).
It is pious to isolate the text from the only remaining evidence!
That is the final step and the last warning before "It means what we tell you it means"
We can then look back at Numbers 21:5 where the major translations know that they can't tell what הַקְּלֹקֵֽל׃ means, but they all translate it anyway. And so the cadavre exquis is not intact, a piece has been stolen. (I imply of course that the 'dying-and-rising god' motif was a hermeneutic marker acknowledging a tradition has federated and assimilated multiple precursors.)

FelixLXX, do you have support for the bait-and-switch interpretation for Matthew 7? I don't see any specification there, and the Numbers 21 situation seems be to responsive anger rather than anticipatory trickery.

Yes. The Plautus citation is Aulularia 2.2, where Euclio's problem is he's been given a bride who (he's saying) will take all his money. Erasmus' explanation of the aphorism (i) fits and (ii) fits better.

FelixLXX, I don't want to speak for mjc if he doesn't think you're getting him wrong--but it seems to me that you might be doing so. Or at least overlooking an important point in the vicinity. Whether or not Jesus was intentionally trying to make people think of the event in Numbers is not very important (arguably he was not). The real question is, why did he pick an archetypal example of a contrast between good & evil which Yahweh very pointedly violated in earlier scripture? It looks to me like yet another, and to my knowledge previously unemphasized, biblical contradiction.

@scottef the familiar-from-comedy evil is the bait-and-switch, which God hadn't earlier violated. In Numbers 21 we don't know and can't tell if God had violated anything because we can't read the key word. I think they have moved this to chat though.

FelixLXX I don't see in the text, or your answer, the slightest reason to think that Jesus meant that "bait and switch" was the mark of doing wrong. Rather it is simply, as the text says, giving someone not what they ask for (presuming the asking is reasonable, and of something truly valuable/needed), but something harmful instead (as mjc pointed out). The Plautus "two handed" reference is the closest to this idea in your sources, but it is very implausible that Jesus' audience would be more familiar with this Latin source than with the better-matching story from Numbers.

Well I find it implausible that they gain less meaning from Jesus using the aphorism than a comedy audience did from Plautus using the aphorism. That's making them immensely thick or reserving them into a magical language-bubble to avoid adequately accounting for Jesus' use of language.

+1 for detail and erudition, FelixLXX. I accept that  if Matthew is composing freely then Plautus is a plausible target for the allusion. If the words are those of an historical Jesus, a working class Galilean who read at least Isaiah, I would think him knowing Plautus would be less likely. Though some of his audience might have known Plautus but not Numbers, since according to Matthew 4:25, the crowd was drawn "from Galilee, and from Decapolis, and from Jerusalem, and from Judaea, and from beyond Jordan.".

"If people want to tell others (i) that the bible is infallible and (ii) what it means, they cannot admit that Jesus uses adages" - why not? Paul openly quotes pagan authors a few times. Is there any reason Jesus can't, or they can't both be referencing a well-known proverb? +1 for the very interesting reference to Plautus, but I fail to see the problem claimed for fundamentalism.
